# jQuery Mobile on Android: back button brings 2 pages back

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile website based on jQuery mobile 1.1.0 and faced a problem when testing it on Android (2.3.3 version, default built in browser). When navigating through website, if I press back button, the site throws me two pages back, instead of one.

Here is site for testing with minimal code, no additional javascript, just jQuery and jQuery Mobile included.

http://aaa.srv7.321.lt/

You can see that by going to mail->choose mail message->then press back.  Actually by going in to first single mail message, pressing back brings one page back. But if you go to another, then back button will start bringing you 2 pages back.

On iPhone there is no such problem. Also, disabling ajax page loading fixes the problem.

Comment: works fine on firefox... where do you get this issue?

Comment: As I wrote, I get this problem namely on Android device.

Comment: I can also add that in the same website, if I added many pages, navigating from page to page is not smooth, it seems like every page is being loaded twice. This is also visible only on Android devices.

Firebug does not show double page loading.

Comment: it's a bug in android.and there is a same problem.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937629/jquery-mobile-back-button-double-back-android-only