# jquery-mobile - back button double back - Android only

Tags: jquery-mobile, back-button

Link with data-rel="back" causes two (double) back transitions instead of a single. The issue seems to be Android related - demonstrated in 2.2 and 2.3.

page 1 -> page 2 -> page 3

If the user clicks the back link on page 3 the following will happen:
back link -> (page 2 temp) -> page 1

Attempted to disable pushStateEnabled without success

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( window ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Also attempted and double back persists

```
<a href="/" onclick="history.back(-1)" >Back</a>
```

Any suggestions/update to deliver expected back functionality?

Comment: could you post the anchor tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your anchor tags are correct I don't see why `$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;` does not work.

Maybe using 'document' as your selector instead of 'window' will do the trick.

Did you try?

```
<script>
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: 'document' is the the fix - that does it

Answer (score 0):

@Phill
you can open the [jquery mobile library pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/index.html) to the android 2.2 or 2.3 device.
if you open the index page, first click 'Page transitions',second open any transition page and click the 'Take me back' button,some time it will take back to 'Page transitions' page.

Answer (score 0):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html

**data-rel**

> *back* (to move one step back in history)
>   *dialog* (to open link styled as dialog, not tracked in history)
>   *external* (for linking to another domain)

use the attribute data-rel="back" on the anchor tag instead of the hash navigation, this will take you to the previous page

Example:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

Related:

- [jQuery Mobile - back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740934/jquerymobile-backbutton/5743997#5743997)